# Auto renewable option for in app purchase is not visible

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

[image: Auto renewable subscription no visible]

I need to create an annual auto renewing payment plan, but I'm not getting the options for this, Usually there should have been four options including an auto renewing subscription.

Answer (score 0):

To make it visible you should confirm all agreements, fill contact and bank account information and request Paid Application Contract.